# how does django get_next_by_FOO() query work?

Tags: sql, django, database, django-orm

i want to know how get_next_by_FOO()/get_previous_by_FOO() fetch data from database. anyone know the SQL code for that?. can anyone tell me how it works behind the scene?

Comment: It will query with something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field > field_value ORDER BY field ASC LIMIT 1` and `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field < field_value ORDER BY field DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is implemented in the [**`django/db/models/base.py`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/db/models/base.py#L947-L961) file:

> ```
>     def _get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD(self, field, is_next, **kwargs):
>         if not self.pk:
>             raise ValueError("get_next/get_previous cannot be used on unsaved objects.")
>         op = 'gt' if is_next else 'lt'
>         order = '' if is_next else '-'
>         param = getattr(self, field.attname)
>         q = Q(**{'%s__%s' % (field.name, op): param})
>         q = q | Q(**{field.name: param, 'pk__%s' % op: self.pk})
>         qs = self.__class__._default_manager.using(self._state.db).filter(**kwargs).filter(q).order_by(
>             '%s%s' % (order, field.name), '%spk' % order
>         )
>         try:
>             return qs[0]
>         except IndexError:
>             raise self.DoesNotExist("%s matching query does not exist." % self.__class__._meta.object_name)
> ```

The `is_next` will be `True` if you query for `get_next_by_FOO`, and `False` if you query for `get_previous_by_FOO`.

For the `get_next_by_FOO` this thus will create a query that looks like:

```
Model.objects.filter(
    Q(FOO__gt=current_foo)
    Q(FOO=current_foo, pk__gt=current_pk)
).order_by('FOO', 'pk')[0]
```

It thus will search for the first `Model` objects where the `FOO` field is the same, but the primary key is greater, or where the `FOO` field is (strictly) larger.

This thus will result in query that looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM model
WHERE FOO > current_FOO
   OR (FOO = current_FOO AND id > current_pk)
ORDER BY FOO ASC, id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

It will thus aim to find that element by ordering the records, and fetching the first one.

For `get_previous_by_FOO`, the query is similar, except that `>` is replaced with `<` and we order in the opposite way:

```
SELECT *
FROM model
WHERE FOO < current_FOO
   OR (FOO = current_FOO AND id < current_pk)
ORDER BY FOO DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: i have a publish_date field which is set as null=True. i.e if blog is not published, publish_date is null. can i use get_next_by_F00() on publish_date field like get_next_by_publish_date.

Comment: @ashleyparker: it will not raise an error. But the problem is that the order of `NULL` is unspecified, so in some databases it can be at the top (ordered as the smallest elements), the largest, or even just without an order, so randomly scrambled.

Comment: i am using postgresql . will it work on postgresql. obj.get_next_by_publish_date(published=True). fields are publish_date(datetimefield,null=True), published(booleanfield). or should i write my own get_next_by

Comment: @ashleyparker: You can filter with `obj.get_next_by_publish_date(publish_date__isnull=False)` to filter out `NULL`s from the `publish_date`.

Comment: thanks @Willem. one more question. if i work on one million records. how is the performance(how much time will it take to fetch next item or previous item)

Comment: @ashleyparker: if you make use of an index, so `pubhish_date = models.DateField(db_index=True)`, it should normally work in *O(log n)*, which should be scalable.